# Rotate Camera in the Direction behind object in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glut

I'm making a game in OpenGL, using freeglut.

I have a car, which I am able to move back and forward using keys and the camera follows it. Now, when I turn the car(glRotate in xz plane), I want the camera to change the Camera position(using gluLookAt) so it always points to the back of the car.

Any suggestions how do I do that?

Comment: The camera always points to the back of the car ... does the camera also need to follow the car? I.e. should the camera stay behind the car?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. I tried manipulating the values of direction vectors (sin/cos), but I don't know much about it so I am not sure. Let me know if you have any suggestions about it, and I can try figuring out again. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203909%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx. While it is C#/XNA, it would give you idea of math behind this - after all, camera is all about math and transformation order.

Answer (score 0):

For camera follow I use the object transform matrix

1. **get object transform matrix**

   ```
   camera=object
   ```

   use `glGetMatrix` or whatever for that
2. **shift rotate the position so `Z` axis is directing where you want to look**

   I use object aligned to forward on `Z` axis, but not all mesh models are like this so rotate by `(+/-)90 deg` around `x,y` or `z` to match this:

   - `Z`-axis is forward (or backward depends on your projection matrix and depth function)
   - `X`-axis is Right
   - `Y`-axis is Up

   with respect to your camera/screen coordinate system (projection matrix). Then translate to behind position
3. **apply `POV` rotation (optional)**

   if you can slightly rotate camera view from forward direction (mouse look) then do it at this step

   ```
   camera*=rotation_POV
   ```
4. **convert matrix to camera**

   camera matrix is usually inverse of the coordinate system matrix it represents so:

   ```
   camera=Inverse(camera)
   ```

For more info look here [understanding transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) the **OpenGL** inverse matrix computation in **C++** is included there.